# sending Facebook messages with python script

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku

i'm trying to find a way to send Facebook messages using a python scripts on my computer (e.g. something like send_msg(user_id, msg)). I figured the Facebook API would make this process easy but i was wrong (i don't have much experience with APIs). It seems the only way to automate sending messages is to host the script (flask app) on some server (e.g. Heroku) where Facebook will communicate exclusively with it and bypass my computer all together. I want to know if this really is the only way of communicating with the Facebook API.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “sending messages”? Are you talking about a messenger bot, or something else?

Comment: the functionality i need is for a script to be able to send (and receive) Facebook messages from an arbitrary Facebook user i.e. script logs into some specified facebook account and sends messages just the way a normal user would only without the fuss of a browser

Comment: There is no API for that.